# script stop execution without showing error

Tags: php, mysql, execution-time

Here is my problem

I am comparing an image uploaded by user against images I already have stored on my database.

Currently I have approx 800 record in the image table.

But when script run it stop execution after few seconds.

I have tried below approaches.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//session_write_close();
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
set_time_limit(0);
```

But none of the above worked.

When the script stops execution it shows me this error

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found
```

in firebug.

[`Reference code link which i use for comparing images`](http://compareimages.nikhazy-dizajn.hu/)

Comment: Seems like function ignore_user_abort requires a page which is not available.hence 404.

Comment: @Vivek can not get it, can you show some reference about what you are saying...Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code for function ignore_user_abort() ?

Comment: @Vivek well its not created by me, its [php built in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: @user3663507 Please try adding the below 2 lines at top of the file 

ini_set("max_execution_time",0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Comment: @Veerendra :(  sorry not worked i have already tried it.

Comment: Guys - Surely you are all looking at the wrong problem. The issue is `NetworkError: 404 Not Found` so it is looking for something it is not finding. **Show the actual code you are running** _not just a link to the original code_! The problem is **nothing to do with script timing out**, yet.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah you might be right, but when i use `LIMIT 0,30` in SQL it works but when i add even `LIMIT 0,31` it fails. I have also checked 31 record and images path is correct, and FYI : i am doing nothing fancy then image compare code i shared in link all i do extra is calling this class function as per record i receive from Mysql image table.

Comment: Have you checked the `php error log`, if it is timing out there will be a message in the log. Also try selecting all rows in one query and echo out something before starting each image compare so you know where you are just before whatever it is causes the failure.

Comment: @RiggsFolly php error log showing nothing. and yes i have also tried echoing when each image is processed even when all images are processed but none of them worked, all try i get blank screen, but as i said in past comment when i use limit clause in mysql and select few records that is works great.

Comment: Well then you can be fairly sure its not blowing you `max_execution_time` then always assuming you are running with PHP set to log errors to the error.log So you need to look elsewhere